# Limit the number of error messages from `gcc`

Tags: gcc

The error output of `gcc` can become very large. This is especially annoying when I am using static assertions and am not interested in any messages that come after the failed assertion.

Is it possible limit the number of errors reported by `gcc`?

Comment: The edit modified the question's intention. It should not have the `shell` tag.

Comment: Sorry for confusion, I removed it

Comment: @bigOTHER Thank you. I understood your good intention, but the tag resulted in answers going the wrong direction :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When looking up the `gcc` manual page on `-Wfatal-errors` (see the answer by @undur_gongor), I stumbled upon the option that directly answers my question:

```
-fmax-errors=n
```

Comment: Yes, it is ok. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252491/how-would-i-award-my-own-eureka-moment

Comment: @undur_gongor It is quite impressive that you say this despite the fact that it is your answer that will be unchecked! Well, I also lost my two points by not accepting someone else's answer...

Answer (score 3):

Better forward the `stdout` and `stderr` to a file so you will have no output on shell:

```
gcc file.c 1> compile.log 2>&1
```

Or you can pipe it to a command like `head` to take only the first lines:

```
gcc test.c 2>&1 | head -n 5
```

Or filtering it using `grep`:

```
gcc test.c 2>&1 | grep "error"
```

Comment: I am compiling from within `Emacs`, so the output of `gcc` is already in an `Emacs` buffer.

Answer (score 3):

The option

```
-Wfatal-errors
```

makes gcc stop compilation at the first error encountered.

If you combine it with

```
-Werror
```

you can stop at the first warning.

Comment: This is the first answer to the question that was asked. Note that the original  question did not have the `shell` tag. It should be forbidden to edit tags without the author's permission, since an extra tag can modify the intention of the question.

Comment: Oops. `-Wfatal-errors` also cuts down on the first error message. For example, when the error is `no matching function for call`, it does not go ahead to tell me the closest candidates and which conversion failed. Is there a way to have everything related to the first error?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: As far as I know, no.

Comment: `-fmax-errors=2` is the best I found... (see my reply below)